# Utility to Record Sensor Data after Safety Event

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During robot operations there may be a safety event that interrupts the process and should be documented. The **prior** 10-20 seconds of sensor data (lidar, odom, vision) would be good documentation about the event and we would like to have this data saved to the disk after the safety event is triggered.

Is there any pre-existing utility (particularly related to bag files) that can be used to produce this behavior (i.e. save the last 20 seconds of sensor data to disk after a boolean condition is triggered)?

Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364466/utility-to-record-sensor-data-after-safety-event/) by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 977 on 2020-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not safety-rated, but [ros/rosbag_snapshot](https://github.com/ros/rosbag_snapshot) seems like it would cover your use-case:

> Solution for [this ros_comm issue](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1399) which acts similarly to the deprecated `rosrecord -s` command but with additional features. It is added as a new package here rather than patching `rosbag` based on the discussion here.
>
> It subscribes to topics and maintains a buffer of recent messages like a dash cam. This is useful in live testing where unexpected events can occur which would be useful to have data on but the opportunity is missed if `rosbag record` was not running (disk space limits make always running `rosbag record` impracticable). Instead, users may run snapshot in the background and save data from the recent past to disk as needed.

Note: `rosbag_snapshot` has been released into both Kinetic, Melodic and Noetic, so no need to build it from source (`sudo apt install ros-*-rosbag-snapshot` should work on supported platforms).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would go about that using http://wiki.ros.org/mongodb_log. The use-case you describe is similar to what they describe under "Application in fault Analysis" on their [project page](https://www.fawkesrobotics.org/projects/mongodb-log/). Using mongodb for storage of time-stamped messages clearly provides you with more flexibility in terms of retrieval than a sequentially written bag file. Assuming that mongodb_log already indexes their collection by `__recorded` you should be able to retrieve the last X seconds easily and also regularly delete anything older than that.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-31**:
Yes, Mongo DB is a good tool for this. Also not ROS-specific, so could be useful for other things as well.